# Convert English numbers in a String to Arabic numbers

Tags: android, textview, string-formatting

I have multiple strings with different formats that I need to display in some TextViews. I have no control over the length or the format of these strings. They could have numbers obly, text only, or a combination of both.

My goal is to display the strings in some TextViews, and in the process, convert any English numbers to Arabic numbers.

The following examples should clarify what I mean:

```
original string   >> converted string
=====================================
test 123          >> test ١٢٣
test              >> test
123               >> ١٢٣
```

I started by doing this:

```
txtView.setText(String.format(locale, "%d", fulltext));
```

but this assumes you have numbers only in your `fulltext` string.

Could you suggest how to work around this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lets say your fulltext string is this

```
String fulltext = "1a2b3c";
```

Replace the instances of all of the numbers with the corresponding Arabic numbers

```
fulltext = fulltext.replace("1","١").replace("2","٢").replace("3","٣");
```

etc. Hopefully this is what you mean

Comment: Works perfectly! Never though of using `replaceAll()`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Also, there might be a way to do this in one line using some sort of regex, but I wasn't able to figure that out

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. One regex call might be better (in terms of performance) than 10 replaceAll calls.

Answer (score 4):

```
String val="123";char[] arabicChars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0;i<val.length();i++){
     if(Character.isDigit(val.charAt(i))){
          builder.append(arabicChars[(int)(val.charAt(i))-48]);
     }
     else{
          builder.append(val.charAt(i));
     }
 }
system.out.println(""+builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your number in persian or arabic format, you must use persian or arabic fonts. With android studio's default font you see them in English format . So do like this:
1. Go to this address 
File \new \ folder \ assets folder
You can create a folder that is named as fonts
2. For your textview or edittext that you want to change it's font should do as this

Typeface face=Typeface.createformatassest (getassest (),"fonts/BZAR.TTF");
Textview.settypeface (face);

Fonts is my folder in assets folder.

If you use persian or arabic fonts your numbers format become to arabic format.

Comment: I'm using a Persian/Farsi font (IranSans) but the numbers are shown in english. Your answer works on phones who have set their language to Arabic or Farsi not those who are using English as their phone language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: (ES6)

```
export const eArabic = (text) => {

    let newString = "";

    const arabicChars = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];

    [...`${text}`].map(item => {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(item))) {

            newString += arabicChars[parseInt(item)];
        } else {
            newString += item;
        }
    });

    return newString;
};
```